# How to enable ECDHE in openjdk-1.8.0 in CentOS 6.7?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, web-browser

I have seen many posts that hinted ECDHE is available in the SunEC provider
way back in openjdk-1.6.0.
My environment: CentOS 6.7 with openjdk 1.8.0.71-1.b15.el6_7. No ECDHE.

Made 2 changes in jre/lib/security/java.security:
- Add back security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC and bump the rest 
  providers down to 4,5,6,etc.
- jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768
  i.e. removed EC, ECDHE, ECDH from the disabled list.

Did not change anything.
How can I get ECDHE working in openjdk?
By the way: heard about Bouncy Castle but hopefull don't have to go that
way if openjdk supports ECDHE.

Comment: does this help: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/27252/nss-configuration-pkcs11-provider-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RedHat** and thus CentOS **removed** EC crypto from many packages, 
not just OpenJDK but also OpenSSL OpenSSH NSS at least, until late 2013; restoring it in has been piecemeal and gradual.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1208307 shows openjdk-1.8.0 fixed by 91-1.b14.el6 released 2016-05-10 by https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2016-0816.html -- but using NSS not upstream SunEC. My CentOS 6.7 shows 101-3.b13 available but I haven't had time to (re)test.

Comment: Tried to enable ECDHE in openjdk version 91-1.b14 (as mentioned in RedHat errata RHEA-2016-0816), did not work. The java.security file still has EC, ECDHE and ECDH listed in disabledAlgorithm. Then in openjdk 101-3.b13 ECDHE works!

Comment: I'm getting no satisfaction on my Amazon Linux (RHEL-compatible) package also at version `1.8.0_101-b13`.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to append my thoughts to this since I've been recently going through the same thing.

All my attempts of trying to get ECDHE with SunEC have been pretty unsuccessful, so I'd strongly recommend just using Bouncy Castle. You just add the provider jar to your JRE/JDK ext folders and modify your security providers in your java security file and boom, you're ready to go.

Comment: This discussion contains a more detailed description how to install Bouncy Castle, and other hints how to enable ECDHE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971499/ecdhe-cipher-suites-not-supported-on-openjdk-8-installed-on-ec2-linux-machine